# Problem using jquery to calculate coordinates

Tags: jquery

Hello i'm trying to center an arrow in a picture using jquery... the arrow will serve for navigation trought my picture. My problem is i can't center the arrow....

here is my code:

I changed the id with the class name and it's still not working ill link the js css and html to you

html/php

```
    <div id="large" class="loader">
           <div id="test5"> 
            <img src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/images/right.gif" class="right" width="38" height="48" alt="right"/>
            <img src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/images/left.gif" width="38" height="48" class="left" />  
            <center><img src="<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>" class="photo_large"/><center>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css

```
#large {
padding-top:25px;   
margin: 0 auto;
width:700px;
max-height:500px;   
padding-bottom:25px;
position:relative;

}

.photo_large{

    resize:both;
    border: solid 5px #fff;
    max-height:390px;
    max-width:600px;
    resize:both;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}


#test5{
    position:relative;

}


.right {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;

}

.left {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;

}
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".right").css("top", ($(".photo_large").height()/2) - ($(".right").height()/2));
    $(".right").css("left", ($(".photo_large").width()/2) - ($(".right").width()/2));    
});
```

Comment: A note: You're using `$("#right").each();`  In theory, an id should only be on one element, so running `$("#right").each()` shouldn't really do anything.  If you are using the same ID for multiple elements, I suggest that you use classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#right").css("top", (($("#photo_large").height() - $(this).height())/2 + "px"));
});
```

A note: You're using `$("#right").each();` In theory, an id should only be on one element, so running `$("#right").each();` shouldn't really do anything. If you are using the same ID for multiple elements, I suggest that you use classes.

Answer (score 0):

Is #photo_large a child of #right? If so, the issue you're likely having is that jQuery's trying to manipulate every #photo_large on page.

```
$(function() {

$("#right").each(function() {

    var h = $(this).children("#photo_large").height();

    var hr = $(this).height();

    $(this).css("top", ((h - hr)/2 + "px"));

});


});
```

Agreed with Switz, though; use classes for objects that repeat, IDs for things that are only placed once per page in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

You need a little more CSS, I believe. Check my Live Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/pgHqZ/1/

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#right").css("top", ($("#photo_large").height()/2) - ($("#right").height()/2));
    $("#right").css("left", ($("#photo_large").width()/2) - ($("#right").width()/2));    
});
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x300/ffc/000&text=Picture1" id="photo_large">
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/30x30/f00/fff&text=>" id="right">
```

**CSS**

```
#photo_large{
    z-index:998;
}
#right{
    z-index:999;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: It do work in firefox but not in safarie. also i noticed that when the image height change, the arrow dosnt stay in the middle of the image... it stay fix with the height of the first image. sorry for my english i'M french!